# Making Changes To A Live HTML File From OfficeLibre Writer On Same Server

Tags: centos, security, apache-httpd, selinux, html

I have discussed this issue briefly in ##linux freednode twice over the past few months.  Once I got crucified;

> *WHY WOULD YOU DO THIS!?*

and second conversation I wasn't pleased with the results of the discussion so here I am.

**What I would like to achieve if I could wave my magic wizard wand successfully:**

I want to know if it is possible to load /var/www/domainname/public_html/index.html in OfficeLibre Writer and edit index.html of a working domain on my server, press save and my site updates to the web.  Simple.  Right...?

I opened /var/www/domainname/public_html/index.html in OfficeLibre Writer made changes to the file went to save, OfficeLibre Writer asked me to overwrite so I did but then got error `Error saving the document index: "/var/www/domainname/public_html/index.html was denied.`

Then I press Okay and get:

```
Error saving the document index: General Error.  General input/output error.
```

---

I am using CentOS7 as a server and work station.

I can see why CentOS would have an issue from a security point of view.  If we can put humans on the moon I believe the result I am seeking is obtainable.

---

So I ran `soffice --writer` opened the index.html file, made minor changes, saved and pressed refresh on the browser and yeah the process went through but the result was not what I expected.  Result was the code and not the graphical webpage I had before.

mikekaganski from freenode said

> *I mean that Writer is not intended to be a neat HTML editor preserving its structure; it imports any textual data into its document model (totally unrelated to HTML DOM), and then on export, it makes another conversion from its model into the target format ... and that's expected *not* to preserve the structure*

Makes sense, I guess what I was trying to do is "integrate" two separate software expecting them to "synchronize" with one another.

I did notice this on the cli

```
[orca@orcacomputers bin]$ sudo soffice --writer
[sudo] password for orca: 
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
Gtk-Message: 00:51:56.654: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

---

Okay sure, so my curiosity was still not satisfied so I made a new test.html file that didn't exist previously to see if I could get my result however I got

> *file does not exist*

So does not look like this is possible.

Is this possible using Atom is my next test.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is possibly because the index.html file is inside a root owned directory, try running LibreOffice with superuser privileges, if that doesn't work, try to edit the file with nano or vim, if its successful then the problem lies with LibreOffice.

Atom is a very nice and kind lightweight IDE, it supports syntax highlighting for html, if you don't have vnc access you can use X11 forwarding.

Comment: added new results to post